# required: 'android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner error

Tags: android, android-room

I want to create a utility class that will manage my Room database. Using live data, I am able to observe changes within my database, however, I can only place this observer in my Activity class. I want to confirm that this is really the case. I have tried to use both a context and Activity as a perimeter.

I have also added the following library to gradle

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
```

Here is an example of how I use the observer

```
   public DatabaseUtils(AppDatabase db,  Context context) {
        db.testDao().getAllLiveList().observe(
                context, new Observer<List<TestEntity>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<TestEntity> testEntities) {
                       // do work

                    }
                });

    }
```

This works fine in an Activity, but moved to a class that does not extend Activity I am receiving the error :

Wrong 1st argument. Found....required: 'android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because [LiveData.observe](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html#observe(android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,%20android.arch.lifecycle.Observer%3CT%3E)) takes `LifecycleOwner` as its first argument and not a `Context`, and an activity is also a `LifecycleOwner`:

```
public class SupportActivity extends Activity implements LifecycleOwner {
    // Your activity may be a subclass of this activity.
}
```

So you probably want to pass a `LifecycleOwner` instead of a `Context` to your `DatabaseUtil`. Or you can use [LiveData.observeForever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html#observeforever) if you do not care about the lifecycle.